# Differentitaion of a non-linear equation using FDM method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

I'm a Ph.D student of Hydraulic structures. I'm reading a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0307904X80901742/pdf?md5=b7be1a83c5009c5547f631d5ab7f87b0&pid=1-s2.0-0307904X80901742-main.pdf) in that the equation $(II)$ below is obtained by differentiating the equation $(I)$ using FDE (Finite Difference Equation) method and 'upwind' scheme.unfortunately I wasn't able to get the details by myself.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(C_T\frac{\rho u^2}{2}\right)=\frac{dp}{dx}-\frac{f\rho u^2p}{8Ar} \ , \quad \quad (I)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D_iu_i=A_i u_{i+1}+B_iu_{i-1}+Ar(p_i-p_{i+1})+C_i\ , \quad \quad (II)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{eqnarray}
A_i & = &C_T\{-(\rho uAr)_{i+1}\}, \\
B_i & = &C_T(uAr)_{i-1}, \\
C_i & = &-\frac{f}{8}u_i^2p_ix_i, \\
D_i & = & A_i+B_i \ .
\end{eqnarray}
In the above equations $C_T, \rho, f$ and $Ar$ are constants, $u=u(x), p=p(x)$ are differentiable functions of the non-negative real variable $x$ and $A, B, C$ and $D$ are the coefficients of FDE.
Here I have two questions:
1. How does the equation $(I)$ gives the equation $(II)$?
2. It's been said in the paper that the equation $(II)$ can be solved by Tri-Diagonal Matrix Algorithm (TDMA), while the equation $(II)$ leads to a non-linear system of equations. So, my second question is that how can TDMA be applied to a non-linear system of equations?

Comment: Isn't there a $\rho$ missing within the parenthesis of term $B_i$?

Comment: No, there is't any $\rho$ in term $B_i$.

Comment: That is strange, because you're then adding two terms, $A_iu_{i+1}$ and $B_iu_{i-1}$ that clearly do not have the same dimensions. It is like adding apples to oranges. I would humbly say that Eq. (16) in the paper you mentioned contains a typo. This presumed error propagates to the "central" term $D_iu_i$, as it also contains $B_i$.

Comment: Also, the $p$ in the 2nd term of the RHS of $(I)$ is not correct. It should appear as $P$ (perimeter) rather than $p$ (pressure). The article shows it correctly, $P$. Thus $(I)$ is dimensionally correct, with all terms $ML^{-2}T^{-2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention, you are right and $P$ is perimeter in RSH of $(I)$. Do you know how the equation $(I)$ leads to equation  $(II)$?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. If I work $(I)$ out I will never get to $(II)$. I can't make much sense out of what the author did. Take $C_i$ as an example. Whatever happened to $\rho$? $(I)$ was not divided by $\rho$, thus it shouldn't have been removed from $C_i$. Where did $p_i$ come? The integration is in $x$, not $p$. He might have made $\rho u_i^2 = p_i$ (what would explain the disappearance of $\rho$) but $u_i^2$ is still there. Finally, $C_i$ dimension is $ML^2T^{-4}$, which is not in agreement with the other terms in $(II)$. I really don't know what to think.

Comment: I will play with your equations a bit more, but I'm kind of hopeless. I would suggest you to talk to your supervisor in the meantime. Also, check whether the author published an erratum. Typos are quite frequent.

Comment: I'm so grateful for your attention, I will check it. I think you are right about $C_i$ in equation $(II)$. Also, It's been said in the paper that the equation $(II)$ can be solved by Tri-Diagonal Matrix Algorithm (TDMA), while the equation $(II)$ leads to a non-linear system of equations. However, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can solve a system in terms of $u^2$ with TDMA, that won't be a big problem I think (in this case, $u^2$ would be one of $\textbf{x}$ terms in $\textbf{Ax = b}$). $(II)$ is a one-dimensional, steady-state system of equations, thus it can be solved with TDMA.